# Is working in insurance company allowed if the Sharia Council of that country has approved it to be following Sharia rules?

Tags: riba, insurance

I have been offered a job from a medical insurance company to work in their head office. In their profile they say that their company's operations are approved by Shariah Review Bureau (this multinational company is in Saudi Arabia).

Do I still need to research more on it from other sources before i join them?

Answer (score 0):

The Shariya Review Bureau you cite (SRB) is licenced by the central bank of Bahrain and claims to be one of the leading Sharia advisory companies in the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia. It appears to be reputable so you should be able to ask for confirmation of the SRB's approval of this company.

It would also be worth while to confirm yourself that the company structure is takaful-style (co-operative or mutual style).

Answer (score -2):

Insurance is NOT HARAM!!! it's more risky to not have insurance than it is to have insurance. You don't know the outcome of any investment you make! in fact if you did know the outcome that would be RIBA!

Comment: plz learn [how to answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/answering)